# Using @Async or @Scheduled in non-singletons

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Need some quick help.

1. Is it possible to make a class annotated with `@Service` to be a non-singleton, in a way that I can use `Clazz c = new Clazz();` and it creates a new object?
2. If not: Is it possible to use `@Async` and `@Scheduled` in a class that is not annotated with `@Component` or `@Service`?

cheers!

Comment: Why would you *want* `@Service`, if you're going to instantiate it yourself?  What's the value?

Comment: @skaffman because i need to make use of @Async and @Scheduled

Comment: You can't make use of @Async and @Scheduled, only Spring can. So if you instantiate your own instance it won't apply.

Comment: Take a look at `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` if you want to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a non-singleton, spring-managed object, declare it with `scope="prototype"` (or `@Scope("prototype")`. If you want to inject prototype-scoped beans into a singleton, you can use a `lookup-method`. A new object will be returned on each invocation of the method. [this is how it is done with xml](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection).

You *can* have objects that you instantiate managed by spring by using an aspectj weaver and `@Configurable`, but it's not something I'd recommend.

You can have `@Async` and `@Scheduled` on any spring-managed bean. There are multiple ways to define it as such: annotation (`@Service`), xml config, or java config.

Comment: "You can have objects that you instantiate managed by spring by using an aspectj weaver and @Configurable, but it's not something I'd recommend." Why not? Do you have any links/tutorials pointing me in the right direction? thanks a lot

Comment: Actually did it using the @Configurable and AspectJ LTW on an apache tomcat. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @chzbrgla I personally don't like it, because it's 'black magic'. What the weaver does is it plug in into the compiler, or the JVM and assigns these objects to the context. It is not done by the normal inversion of control mechanism behinds dependency injection.

Comment: Ok that's a good point though. For this use-case however I couldn't come up with any other solution - hence the SO post :).

Comment: @chzbrgla isn't there a way to utilize `prototype` ?

Comment: Have been thinking about that. However I couldn't think of a way to make a new instance using _new_ in my code.

Answer (score 1):

1. The benefit of `@Service` is that Spring will auto-discover, instantiate and manage the bean for you. If they're not singletons, there's no benefit to this annotation.
2. Yes. `@Async` and `@Scheduled` have nothing to do with `@Service` and `@Component`

Comment: ad 2.: Ok.. it has to be spring-managed in any way however, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can instantiate classes marked as`@Service`, just because Spring creates a single instance of it doesn't mean you can't create others.

Comment: If I instantiate a new instance, will the @Autowired annotated fields be injected and can I make use of the @Async/@Scheduled ?

Comment: no it won't work like that. So it's useless and wrong to instantiate the objects yourself.

Comment: Yes it is wrong, I was answering the question if it is possible. What you probably want to use is `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`